# regarding php's soap - a beginner trying to make sense about it

Tags: php, soap

i have read many articles that can be found on soap , i am trying to learn all that i can about it, but none of them make any sense to me. I know the basics of xml and i see alot of xpath being used in the xml examples that are shown on these articles. Do i need to know xpath in order to make sense out of soap?

The reason i want to make sense out of soap is because i have build a custom web app (ecommerce) and i need to display fedex rates during shipout and after looking through fedex the data exchange is through soap. I have tried looking for a php class but they are all outdated since fedex has updated their systems.

I do understand what soap is and how it is used but i cannot find one article that explains in plain english for beginners. If you know of any articles or somehow to help me that would be great.

Comment: Related humor to help you take your mind off of things: "[The "S" stands for Simple](http://wanderingbarque.com/nonintersecting/2006/11/15/the-s-stands-for-simple/)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried looking for a php class but they are all outdated since fedex has updated their systems.

Have you checked FedEx's latest PHP SDK/library?  It was upgraded to use the SOAP method long, long ago when they announced they were retiring the old, non-SOAP API.  Using it will protect you from the *utter insanity* that is SOAP itself.

You don't need to know a single thing about XML *if the SOAP implementation you use* is sane.  PHP's built-in SOAP handler is *absolutely insane*, but in a different way.

Comment: i'm trying to look for it but cant i have seen a few code examples but they give errors. if i can remember the page i got the code from on fedex.com i'd give the errors i got but their site is hard to find data

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a higher level approach to soap - as suggested by others here, it's for the most part something you don't want to mess around with the inner workings of.

The [nusoap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/) php library is used by many, and lets you consume and create web services quite easily.

Comment: do you know of any video tutorials on it?